# Do a php function code on a link

Tags: php, unlink

I'm looking for a way to do a function with php when clicking on a link.
I mean to delete an item when clicking on this link. I got my code set up like this:

```
$files = glob("upload/*.*");

if(count($files) == 0){
echo "No files present";
} else {
foreach ( $files as $file ) {
    $array = explode("/", $file);
    //echo $array[1] . "<br>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $array[1] . "</td>";
    echo '<td><img height="70" width="auto" src=" ' . $file . '" ></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="">Delete item</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
}
```

Comment: Set the href to whatever processing page you have.

Comment: Yep. Something like `<a href="delete_file.php?file='.$file.'">Delete item</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main script:

```
$files = glob("upload/*.*");
if(!count($files)){
   echo "No files present";
} else {
   foreach ($files as $file) {
      $array = explode("/", $file);
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $array[1] . "</td>";
      echo '<td><img height="70" width="auto" src=" ' . $file . '" ></td>';
      echo '<td><a href="delete.php?file='.rawurlencode($file).'">Delete item</a></td>';
      echo "</tr>";
   }
}
```

In your delete script:

```
if (isset($_GET['file']) && $file = rawurldecode($_GET['file'])) {
   if (file_exists('upload/' . $file)) 
      unlink($file);
}
```

You might want to pass in another `$_GET` parameter (secret token) for added security - otherwise it'll open up your uploads directory to permanent threat. You can send a random `sha1()` hash or system-defined configuration value, and have your delete script expect a 40-char string.

Comment: Would this not allow directory traversal and deletion of any file?

Comment: Yes, hence my closing paragraph :)

Comment: You make it out as as long as the script expects any *random* 40-char string it's valid, that however does not make it secure as any 40-char string would work.  What you can do is pass the hash of the known real safe path `sha($file)` and add that to link to then compare on delete script to check the integrity of the filename being passed. Adding a salt, wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: You're absolutely right. There are lots of security protocols you could enforce here, and those two you mention are certainly valid, but it's probably out of the scope of this question.

Comment: @Axll if it works for you, feel free to mark this as the accepted answer. Also, take cryptic's advice and look into enforcing security measures with future scripts (especially ones which deal with sensitive operations like deleting files).

Comment: @hohner, i shall indeed take cryptic's advice and make it more secure.
And also a thanks to cryptic off course :)